# Add/change queries to json source url in PHP

Tags: php, json, filter

I have a JSON file that I use to display information within my page via PHP. I can change the display of the results of the JSON with queries such as:

- ?page=1 (it loads 10 entries by default)
- ?fromdate=2017-08-17
- ?sorton=Country

However, I use the base URL for `file_get_contents` and `json_decode`. Is there a way I can change/add queries to this URL later, in for example a loop, so I can create pagination / filter options based on the choices I make on the front end?

My code that loads the JSON:

```
    $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'header'=>"X-AUTH-TOKEN: 34c4c7d79....."
    )
);

$context        = stream_context_create($opts);  
$url            = 'https://urlgoeshere.com'; 
$data           = file_get_contents($url, true, $context); 
$result         = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set your base URL, you can add the query string with options selected on the front end with `http_build_query`.

```
$url = 'https://urlgoeshere.com';
```

You need an array of options.

```
$options = ['page' => 1, 'fromdate' => '2017-08-17', 'sorton' => 'Country'];
```

How you create that array depends on how you're passing the option values from the front end. Here's one example that uses either values from `$_POST` or default values if the relevant keys aren't set.

```
$options = [
    'page' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page') ?? 1,
    'fromdate' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fromdate') ?? date('Y-m-d'),
    'sorton' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sorton') ?? 'Country'
];
```

Then you can build your query and append it to the base URL.

```
$query = http_build_query($options);
$data = file_get_contents("$url?$query", true, $context);
```